# Understanding of Rust Option's unwrap_or_default method

Tags: rust

The document of `an_option.unwrap_or_default()` is this:

> **`pub fn unwrap_or_default(self) -> T`**
>
> Returns the contained Some value or a default. Consumes the self argument then, if Some, returns the contained value, otherwise if None, returns the default value for that type.

I have the following testing program.

```
let a: Option<Option<i32>> = None;
println!("{:#?}", a.unwrap_or_default());
```

When I run it, it outputs `None`. But as I understand, `a` is an `Option` type and is `None`, so the return value should be the default value of `Option<i32>`. I'm not sure what is the default value of `Option<i32>`, maybe `Some(0)`? But I suppose `None` is not the default value of `Option<i32>`. Why the output is `None`? Thanks.

Comment: "But I suppose None is not the default value of Option<i32>" - could you add a little more detail here, for future readers? Probably there's something confusing in documentation.

Comment: @Cerberus It's my misunderstanding. I know the default value of `i32` is `0`, so I take it for granted that `Option<i32>`'s default value should be `Some(0)`. It's not. As @YLyu mentioned, `Option`'s default value is `None`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a is an `Option` of `Option`, the default value of an `Option` is `None`. Check [`Option`'s `Default` trait implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Default)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer explains what's going on, the default value of the inner option being `None`.

As to *why* the default value of `Option` is `None`: if it defaulted to `Some(T::default())`, then `Option` would have to require `T: Default` for the option to be `Default`. Since the point of the `Option` type is to provide a `None` variant that doesn't require a `T` value at all, it's only natural for `Option::default()` to return that variant as the default value.

That maps perfectly to how `Option` is typically used. You *want* it to default to `None` because it means that the actual value hasn't yet been determined. If the default for `Option<i32>` were `Some(0)`, you wouldn't be able to tell whether the option was at its default value or a `0` was already encountered and stored in it.